# Need datepicker which shows date in other format

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want a date picker which gives the date in this format

```
January 19, 2012
```

I already have some date pickers but they are showing dates like this:

```
12/10/2013
```

Comment: is it Jquery datapicker or some other. Please specify.

Comment: Please check your desktop date format at bottom right corner, Most of the date picker will show date format as specified by your desktop date format

Comment: Please mention the programming language which you are using, because it is hard to find question for future user, as well as giving solution also painful.

Comment: no i ve some jquery date pickers but i need a new date picker which ll show date like this  January 19, 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv36W/96/)

**Script**

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'MM dd,yy', onSelect: function (datetext) {
                    $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: what is the jquery for this ??

Comment: yeah ur code is the 1 which i want .. but i cant call the jquery .. i mean the extension ..

<script src="http://jquery.com/jQuery2.x(edge).js"></script>

Not working this jquery... will u write me the proper format

Comment: @sarmistha You no need of extension and all, It will work by ID

Answer (score 4):

Lots of formats [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

You can even customise them. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

set this to ur date picker.

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```